# Floating window strange behaviour on two vertically stacked monitors with M2 Mac Mini running Ventura

Tags: display, mac-mini, window-manager, mission-control, ventura

I have just installed a dual stacked monitor setup and running Ventura 13.2.1 MacOS on an M2 Pro Mac Mini, and am experiencing some very strange behaviour.

If I have a window open - e.g. Safari, and click and drag it such that it spans across the two monitors, if there is less than 50% of the window in the upper screen when I release the mouse, the window will snap down to fill only the bottom screen. If I do the same but have more than 50% of the window in the upper screen the snapping does not happen and the window sits quite happily spanning across both screens (FYI - I have unticked the 'Displays have separate Spaces' option)

I also have the same setup on a different Mac Mini / Ventura with the classic side-by-side monitor setup, and no such issues there. Window will stay spanned across the two monitors, regardless of which one has more than 50% of the floating window in it. So this seems to be a by-product of the vertical stacking arrangement....

One super-weird edge case to consider / see if anyone can replicate. So I set up a Hot Corner to show Mission Control. When I do this and then choose any window from Mission Control (i.e. Safari / System Preferences etc, doesn't really matter) and then perform the same action - i.e. click and drag the Safari window to span across the two screens, if there is less than 50% of the window on the top screen, the snapping to the bottom screen does NOT happen...... it just sits nicely spanned across both screens, just as it should do. But it only works ONCE. If I then try to move the floating window again, it snaps back down to the bottom screen again.

Has anyone figured out a solution to this yet? Driving me mad!!!! Please do let me know if you know why this is happening. It's a brand new Mac / screen so no weird installed 'screen snapping app' - I can only think this is a MacOS bug (feature....ahem)

Comment: As mentioned already: Please add details to the existing question, spreading problem descriptions across several questions doesn't increase the chance of finding answers.

Comment: @nohillside - I can’t add details to the existing question, it says i need ‘50 reputation’ to comment. And the only way for me to get reputation points would be to ask a question…..so do I ask questions about random things that I don’t really need answers to, just to earn reputation points?

Comment: There is an „edit“ link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I understand the „How to get reputation“ problem (and there are various ways to get rep, besides getting upvotes for a  questions). But asking a recently posted, unanswered question again doesn‘t increase the chance for answers.